# yii2 conditional validation on server side

Tags: php, validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have one form that form have below fields

> i)Book
>   ii)Amount

Controller action:

```
public function actionBook()
{   
    $model = new Book();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){ 
        print_r($model);exit;
        return $this->redirect('/Book');
    }
    $model->getBook();
    return $this->render('BookForm', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

Whenever this page will load i will call one model function by default, the function is **getBook()**

Model:

```
public book;
public amount;
public showAmountField;

public function rules()
{   
 return [
  [['book'], 'required'],
  ['amount', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
        return $model->showAmountField == true;
    }],
 ];
}

public function getBook()
{
 if(some condition here){
  $this->showAmountField = true;
 }
}
```

so whenever the showAmountField is true at the time the amount field is required, otherwise it will not required, here all are working fine and the client side validation also working fine, but when i change amount field id using console(f12) at the time the server side validation not working and form is simply submit with the amount field is empty, so what is wrong here. Please explain anyone.

**UPDATE**

View

```
<?php
 use yii\helpers\Html;
 use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
 $this->params['breadcrumb'] = $model->breadCrumbs;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
  'id' => 'book-form',  
  'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
  ]); 
 ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'book')->textInput()->label("Book"); ?>
<?php if($model->showAmountField): ?>      
  <?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput()->label("Amount"); ?>
<?php endif; ?>  
<?= $form->errorSummary($model, ['header' => '']); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: you have to render into same form page in order to see your validation error, moreover you stop the script by adding "exit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$model = new Book();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){ 
    print_r($model);exit;
    return $this->redirect('/Book');
}
$model->getBook();
```

here you are initialising the  $model->getBook(); after the if block so the model gets overridden in post request with new instance and hence server side validations fails for when condition.

```
    $model = new Book();
    $model->getBook();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){ 
        print_r($model);exit;
        return $this->redirect('/Book');
    }
```

it should be before post load

Comment: i want again reinitialize model with that function so that only put below, anyway thank you for your answer. i will do alternative for that.

Answer (score 2):

Validation occurs on the field ID, if you change it through the console, the model does not understand that it needs to validate

Comment: Show your view file

Comment: @VishvaG, he just told you. By changing the element using the console the server doesn't pair it to the model. Try to echo values, step by step, to understand what happens.

Comment: yes i understand obviously client side validation not work,but i dont know why server side validation not work, it's happen only on conditional validation not normal required validation